# Kruskal-Wallis test with details on pairwise comparisons

Tags: r

The standard stats::kruskal.test module allows to calculate the kruskal-wallis test on a dataset:

```
>>> data(diamonds)
>>> kruskal.test(price~carat, data=diamonds)

Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  price by carat by color 
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 50570.15, df = 272, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

This is correct, it is giving me a probability that all the groups in the data have the same mean.

However, I would like to have the details for each pair comparison, like if diamonds of colors D and E have the same mean price, as some other softwares do (SPSS) when you ask for a Kruskal test.

I have found [kruskalmc](http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/pgirmess/man/kruskalmc.html) from the package pgirmess which allows me to do what I want to do:

```
> kruskalmc(diamonds$price, diamonds$color)
Multiple comparison test after Kruskal-Wallis 
p.value: 0.05 
Comparisons
      obs.dif critical.dif difference
D-E  571.7459     747.4962      FALSE
D-F 2237.4309     751.5684       TRUE
D-G 2643.1778     726.9854       TRUE
D-H 4539.4392     774.4809       TRUE
D-I 6002.6286     862.0150       TRUE
D-J 8077.2871    1061.7451       TRUE
E-F 2809.1767     680.4144       TRUE
E-G 3214.9237     653.1587       TRUE
E-H 5111.1851     705.6410       TRUE
E-I 6574.3744     800.7362       TRUE
E-J 8649.0330    1012.6260       TRUE
F-G  405.7470     657.8152      FALSE
F-H 2302.0083     709.9533       TRUE
F-I 3765.1977     804.5390       TRUE
F-J 5839.8562    1015.6357       TRUE
G-H 1896.2614     683.8760       TRUE
G-I 3359.4507     781.6237       TRUE
G-J 5434.1093     997.5813       TRUE
H-I 1463.1894     825.9834       TRUE
H-J 3537.8479    1032.7058       TRUE
I-J 2074.6585    1099.8776       TRUE
```

However, this package only allows for one categoric variable (e.g. I can't study the prices clustered by color and by carat, as I can do with kruskal.test), and I don't know anything about the pgirmess package, whether it is maintained or not, or if it is tested.

Can you recommend me a package to execute the Kruskal-Wallis test which returns details for every comparison? How would you handle the problem?

Comment: There is `kruskal` function in `agricolae` package. You could check if fits your needs.

Comment: Obviously you mean kruskal.test (without the second .test).  I guess you are using the diamonds dataset from ggplot2 package. Well, I can't figure out why, but when I try loading it I get an error `internal error -3 in R_decompress1
In addition: Warning message:
restarting interrupted promise evaluation`. (I know, this looks like a question I should post, but has anyone faced the same problem?)

Comment: @ Marek: thank you very much. I saw agricolae but it seems to have the same problem as pgirmess :-(

@gd047: I have no idea what your error may be, really. Maybe you should try to reinstall ggplot2. Do you have the same error with other datasets or packages?

Comment: I just wonder what makes you think that `kruskal.test` can handle more than one grouping variable. It is a one-way test, after all. If you want to look at all combinations of two factors, just create a new one combining them using `interaction`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One other approach besides kruskal::agricolae mentioned by Marek, is the Nemenyi-Damico-Wolfe-Dunn test implemented in the help page for oneway_test in the coin package that uses multcomp. Using hadley's setup and reducing the B= value for the approximate() function so it finishes in finite time:

```
#updated translation of help page implementation of NDWD
NDWD <- 
    independence_test(dv ~ iv, data = sum_codings1, distribution = approximate(B = 10000), 
                          ytrafo = function(data) trafo(data, numeric_trafo = rank_trafo), 
                          xtrafo = mcp_trafo(iv = "Tukey"))


    ### global p-value
    print(pvalue(NDWD))

    ### sites (I = II) != (III = IV) at alpha = 0.01 (page 244)
    print(pvalue(NDWD, method = "single-step"))
```

More stable results on that larger dataset may require increasing the B value and increasing the user's patience.

Jan: 2012: There was recently a posting on R-help claiming unexpected results from this method so I forwarded that email to the maintainer. Mark Difford said he had confirmed the problems and offered an alternate tests with the nparcomp package:  https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-January/300100.html

There were also in the same week a couple of other suggestions on rhelp for post-hoc contrasts to KW tests:
 [kruskalmc suggested by Mario Garrido Escudero](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-January/300316.html)   and
 `rms::polr` followed by `rms::contrasts` suggested by Frank Harrell https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-January/300329.html

Nov 2015: Agree with toto_tico that help page code of coin package has been changed in the intervening years. The `?independence_test` help page now offers a multivariate-KW test and the `?oneway_test` help page has replace its earlier implementation with the code above usng the `independence_test` function.

Comment: thank you very much, but I can't find any reference for the Nemenyi-Damico-Wolfe-Dunn test. Could you point me to some resources? thanks

Comment: The oneway_test (in pkg=coin) help page cites this in the code:

  " Nemenyi-Damico-Wolfe-Dunn test (joint ranking)
    Hollander & Wolfe (1999), page 244 
    (where Steel-Dwass results are given)"

And this in the References:

Myles Hollander \& Douglas A. Wolfe (1999). Nonparametric Statistical Methods, 2nd Edition. New York: John Wiley & Sons.

Comment: @42- Doesn't Tukey test also assume normality and homogeneity of variance? But here you are suggesting it after a non-parametric test (Kruskal-Wallis). Moreover,  `oneway_test` (with the Monte Carlo aproximation, i.e. `distribution = approximate(B=1000)`) is also non-parametric. How come Tukey is fine for this case?

Comment: @42- In order to get pairwise comparison for the coin package, the `oneway_test` should be replaced with the `independence_test`. The `oneway_test` documenation also suggests the following parameters `NDWD <- independence_test(dv ~ iv, data = sum_codings1, distribution = approximate(B = 10000), ytrafo = function(data) trafo(data, numeric_trafo = rank_trafo), xtrafo = mcp_trafo(iv = "Tukey"))`. If you can point what is the difference, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @toto_tico: I do not see where I suggested using a Tukey test, (nor do I believe that the authors were either.). The use of the "Tukey" style of contrasts is only applied after using a rank transformation that is expected to result in a distribution of errors that meet the distributional assumptions. The original answer was based on the example in the coin package as it stood 5 years ago. In the meantime it has apparently been modified.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PMCMR package. [There](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PMCMR/vignettes/PMCMR.pdf) is more information about it.

```
Spelling_Grades <- c(90,87,89,90,75,88,97,99,78,85,72,76,77,79,70)
Methods <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C")
kruskalmc(Spelling_Grades~Methods)

#This method doesn't accept characters that's why I've changed the methods to integer
Methods <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
posthoc.kruskal.nemenyi.test(Spelling_Grades~Methods)
```

The two methods above give same results.

Comment: `PMCMR` was superseded by [`PMCMRplus`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PMCMRplus/).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know of a function like this. If there isn't one already, it would be an interesting task to construct a function that returns a matrix with all pairwise treatment comparisons. A contrast is considered significant if the following inequality is satisfied

[image]
<sub>(source: [statsdirect.com](http://www.statsdirect.com/help/image/stat0199_wmf.gif))</sub>

where T is the Kruskal-Wallis test statistic for k samples, S^2 is the denominator of the T statistic, N is the total number (all ni) and Ri is the sum of the ranks (from all samples pooled) for the ith sample, and t is a quantile from the Student t distribution on N-k degrees of freedom.

I know I didn't help much :)
I am also waiting for a better answer

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought you'd be able to do the following:

```
data(diamonds, package = "ggplot2")

library(coin)
library(multcomp)

kt <- kruskal_test(price ~ clarity, data = diamonds)
glht(kt, mcp(clarity = "Tukey"))
```

But it seems like `multcomp` doesn't support `coin` objects (yet?).

Comment: ? glht says "General linear hypotheses and multiple comparisons for **parametric** models...", but Kruskal Wallis test is a *non**-parametric test.

Comment: Thanks for the reply even though the origonal post was long time ago - I am dealing with a similar problem myself. Probably I am a complete ignorant - but may I ask you to be a little bit more specific,  I appreciate any help.