# How to test for non-parametric silmultaneous inference in R

Tags: r, testing, simultaneous, inference

I would like to perform non-parametric testing for a dataframe. I have three groups A,B,C. I´d like to now the statistical significance between groups A/B, B/C and A/C.
How can I do that non-parametrically?
When applying Kruskal-Wallis-Test, I get the overall-inference between groups. This serves as protection for the following post-hoc test. But how to program the non-parametric post-hoc test (either using Kruskal-Wallis or Mann-Whitney-U)?

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,NA,9,8)
y<-c(2,3,NA,3,4,NA,2,3,NA,2,3,4)
group<-rep((factor(LETTERS[1:3])),4)
df<-data.frame(x,y,group)
df
```

Comment: i'm flagging for migration as this seems to be a more *which statistical test* question, rather than *how to implement in R*

Comment: No! Actually it is not! The statistical tests are quite clear. This is an programming issue. So far my research did not yield any results for multiple comparison in R using NON-PARAMETRIC tests at all.

Comment: try then to provide in your question which statistical tests you would like to perform then, so other users can quickly show you how to do the test you want.

Comment: you might want to see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2478272/1317221

Comment: and possibly http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20133

Answer (score 2):

ok, just to summarize the discussion within the comments above, there are several (not so well known) possibilities around to perform multiple non-parametric comparison with R-project.
I included two of them for the example above:

```
library(pgrimess)
library(nparcomp)

x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,NA,8,9)
y<-c(2,3,NA,3,4,NA,2,3,NA,2,3,4)
group<-rep((factor(LETTERS[1:3])),4)
df<-data.frame(x,y,group)


kruskal.test(df$x~df$group)
kruskalmc(df$x~df$group)

m<-nparcomp(x ~ group, data=df, asy.method = "probit", type = "Dunnett", control = "A", alternative = "two.sided", info = FALSE)
summary(m)
```

nparcomp is obviously more flexible and allows a large variety of contrasts. Here I picked Dunnett as an example.

There is a proposed procedure for multiple testing, bit according to several posts, there appeared some accuracy problems in large datasets.
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-January/300100.html

```
NDWD <- oneway_test(price ~ clarity, data = diamonds,
        ytrafo = function(data) trafo(data, numeric_trafo = rank),
        xtrafo = function(data) trafo(data, factor_trafo = function(x)
            model.matrix(~x - 1) %*% t(contrMat(table(x), "Tukey"))),
        teststat = "max", distribution = approximate(B=1000))

    ### global p-value
    print(pvalue(NDWD))

    ### sites (I = II) != (III = IV) at alpha = 0.01 (page 244)
    print(pvalue(NDWD, method = "single-step"))
```

Another possibility would be
rms::polr followed by rms::contrasts as suggested by Frank Harrell
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-January/300329.html

Finally, user1317221_G included some very useful links including a boxplot incorporating the 
 results of the test https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20133 and a more detailed description for advanced graphing of boxplots is found one link further at http://egret.psychol.cam.ac.uk/statistics/R/graphs2.html

Hopefully that solves a couple of problems in that sector.