# About post hoc test in the package "agricoale"

Tags: r, package, posthoc

I need a little of help. The function kruskal in the package "agricolae" seems to use a post hoc test. Unfortunately I cant find which post hoc test is in the manuals (even in the spanish one)nor the forums. The man in charge of that package doesnt seem to be interested in answering my e-mail, and I really need to know what post hoc test "kruskal" is doing. Thank you for your time.

Comment: related question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139222/kruskal-wallis-and-post-hoc-analysis-in-r

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kruskal-Wallis test with details on pairwise comparisons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478272/kruskal-wallis-test-with-details-on-pairwise-comparisons)